# How to convert multiple columns from file to single string

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I would like to edit something like this;

```
ABC
abc
123
```

Into something like this;

```
Aa1Bb2Cc3
```

Comment: the number of characters in each line are the same

Comment: please [edit] and add that to your question plus your other comment under accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumming the string are exactly 3 characters long you can do it with `awk` for example. Something like do the work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="" } {a=a$1;b=b$2;c=c$3} END {print a b c}'  input_file >output_file
```

If the length is different and constant over the lines you can use something like:

```
awk -v N=3 'BEGIN {FS="" } { for(i=1;i<=N;i++) a[i]=a[i]$i} END { for(i=1;i<=N;i++) {printf "%s",a[i]};}'   input_file >output_file
```

Replace `3` with the number of chars per line

This will work well on GNU `awk`. Not sure about the rest of variant.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
awk '
    { a[NR] = $0 }
    END {
        n = length(a[1])
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) {
                printf "%s", substr(a[j],i,1)
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
' file
Aa1Bb2Cc3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.comb(); put join "", [Z] @a;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.comb(); put join ",", [Z] @a;'  file
```

The first code example joins all letters together. The second code example joins on commas. Quickly, `lines` are read in and each line is  `comb`ed into single character elements. These are stored in `@a` array. To out`put` the file, each element of the array is `[Z]` "zip" combined/reduced such that all first elements are taken off and combined, all second elements are taken off and combined, etc.

Sample Input:

```
ABC
abc
123
```

Sample Output (first code example):

```
Aa1Bb2Cc3
```

Or you can remove the `join ",",` call and ther return will be joined on single-spaces:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.comb(); put [Z] @a;'  file
A a 1 B b 2 C c 3
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Zip_metaoperator
https://raku.org